# unable to select multiple value using Ajax Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm developing an e-commerce platform in CodeIgniter. I'm trying to do the brand filtering process.
I've got three categories that are `cat1`,`cat2`,`cat3`. Currently, I'm able to fetch the data without refreshing the page but one category only I mean when I click the cat1 I'm able to get the result of `cat1` and so that other category but I want when I click the `cat1` it will give `cat1` result and when I click on the `cat2` it will give the result `cat1 plus cat2`  result. I have tried every possible way I could have done but unable to get the proper result, **also** when I `uncheck` or `click on the selected category again` it still displays the result where it should have stopped filtering form that unchecked category.

**In view**

```
  <ul id="top--cat">
     <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="cates" class="radiochecker" onclick="cat(<?php echo $category['id'] ?>)" >
            <?php echo $category['name'] ?>
          </label>
        </a>
      </li> 
      <?php endforeach; ?>    
    </ul>



<div class="row" id="fetchedprodducts">
       <?php foreach ($products as $pro) : ?> 
        <div class="col-md-3 col-6">
         <a class="all-link--pro" href="<?php echo site_url("product_view/".$pro['id']."/".$pro['slug'])?>">   
            <img class="img-fluid img-size" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/img/posts/".$pro['main_img'])?>">
            <p><?php echo $pro['title'] ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $pro['categoryname'] ?></p>
            <p>Rs. <?php echo $pro['price']; ?></p>
         </a>      
        </div> 
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
```

**In jquery File**

```
  function cat(id){

    $('#catid').val(id);
    cat_filter()
  }

  function cat_filter(){
    var brand_id = $('#catid').val();


    $.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost/tinta/maker/categories/get_procat',
        method:'POST',
        data:{'b_id' : brand_id},
        success:function(data){
            // console.log(data);
            $('#fetchedprodducts').html(data);
        }

    });

  }
```

**Controller**

```
public function get_procat(){
      $brand_id = $this->input->post('b_id');

      $products = $this->Category_model->get_product_by_cat($brand_id);
      $outcome = "";

       if($products) {

        foreach($products as $product){
            $outcome .="<div class='col-md-3 col-6'>  
                        <a class='all-link--pro' href='".site_url('product_view/'.$product['id']."/".$product['slug'])."'>   
                        <img class='img-fluid img-size' src='".base_url('assets/img/posts/'.$product['main_img'])." '>
                        <p>".$product['title']."</p>
                        <p>".$product['categoryname']." </p>
                        <p>Rs ".$product['price']."</p>

                       </a> 
                    </div>";
        }
        echo $outcome ;
      // print_r($products);die;
    }
  }
```

**Model**

```
public function get_product_by_cat($brand_id){


    $this->db->order_by('cv_products.id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->select('cv_products.*, cv_category.name as categoryname, product_line.name as linename,cv_category.id as category_id, delivery_time.name as timingname' );
    $this->db->join('cv_category','cv_category.id = cv_products.category', 'left');
    $this->db->join('product_line','product_line.id = cv_products.product_line', 'left');
    $this->db->join('delivery_time','delivery_time.id = cv_products.timing', 'left');
    $query= $this->db->get_where('cv_products', array('category' => $brand_id));
    return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Comment: little confused. Lets give categories names: pizza, burger, fries. You click pizza, then you click burger and you don't get the results of both? Also I don't see any code anywhere to let the system know that you've already selected pizza, in such a way your code is "dumb" (not you or your implementation ;)) - thus it will always load pizza again when the boxes are unchecked then checked and has no logic to remove a category div when just unchecked. You could store the already rendered ids in an array.

Comment: Yeah.. I want to fetch both data.. Can you please provide me some code to implement these things?

Comment: I'm asking a question too, please re-read

Comment: Look... I'm unable to store all checkbox value in array and unable to fetched that from database too.. What u have understood is totally correct..

Comment: you are using checkboxes with a function attached to every click event. when you click cat1 you should get cat1 and when you click cat2 it should be added after cat1 (or in whatever order you clicked). the only way you can process both requests at the same time is if you don't process everything on click and instead add a button that will process all the checked categories (which i've never really seen in an ui sorting interface). so your current method is good aside from everything after "also" in your above text; the last part is a relatively easy fix.

Comment: So there is no way of getting all the values? And I'm not understanding what should i use whn i click again at it will fetch normal value not filtered one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177244/discussion-between-alex-and-mr-tanmay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a few  modifications to all of your code. Please replace it carefully or parts may not work.

Try this:

**JS** (remove `cat` and `cat_filter` functions - not required):

Note: `append` and other logic checking functions to prevent duplicates and to remove cats when necessary

*UPDATE: added `$('.first-load').remove();`*

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.cat-filter').on('click', function (e) {
        // any checkboxes checked?
        if ($('.cat-filter:checked').length == 0)) {
            $('.first-load').show();
            return;
        } else {
            $('.first-load').hide();
        }
        var brand_id = $(this).attr('data-id');
        console.log('category ' + brand_id);
        // are we unchecking?
        if ($(this).prop('checked') == false) {
            console.log('category ' + brand_id + ' unchecked. hiding contents.');
            $('.cat-' + brand_id).hide();
            return;
        }
        // check if cat is already rendered
        if ($('.cat-' + brand_id).length) {
            $('.cat-' + brand_id).show();
            console.log('category ' + brand_id + ' already rendered. showing contents.');
            return;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/tinta/maker/categories/get_procat',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                b_id: brand_id
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#fetchedprodducts').append(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**CONTROLLER:**

Note: see class added to first div.

```
function get_procat() {
    $brand_id = $this->input->post('b_id');

    if (is_null($brand_id)) {
        exit;
    }

    $products = $this->Category_model->get_product_by_cat($brand_id);

    if ($products) {
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $outcome .= "<div class='col-md-3 col-6 cat-{$brand_id}'>
                        <a class='all-link--pro' href='" . site_url('product_view/' . $product['id'] . "/" . $product['slug']) . "'>   
                        <img class='img-fluid img-size' src='" . base_url('assets/img/posts/' . $product['main_img']) . " '>
                        <p>" . $product['title'] . "</p>
                        <p>" . $product['categoryname'] . " </p>
                        <p>Rs " . $product['price'] . "</p>

                       </a> 
                    </div>";
        }
        echo $outcome;
    }
}
```

**MODEL:**

Returned false if no rows.

```
function get_product_by_cat($brand_id) {
    $this->db->order_by('cv_products.id', 'DESC');
    $this->db->select('cv_products.*, cv_category.name as categoryname, product_line.name as linename,cv_category.id as category_id, delivery_time.name as timingname');
    $this->db->join('cv_category', 'cv_category.id = cv_products.category', 'left');
    $this->db->join('product_line', 'product_line.id = cv_products.product_line', 'left');
    $this->db->join('delivery_time', 'delivery_time.id = cv_products.timing', 'left');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('cv_products', array('category' => $brand_id));
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->result_array();
    }
    return false;
}
```

**VIEW:**

Note: class added and `data-id`, removed function call (not needed anymore).

```
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cates" class="radiochecker cat-filter" data-id="<?php echo $category['id'] ?>">
        <?php echo $category['name'] ?>
      </label>
```

***VIEW PART 2:***
Note: class `first-load` added

```
<div class="row" id="fetchedprodducts">
       <?php foreach ($products as $pro) : ?> 
        <div class="col-md-3 col-6 first-load">
         <a class="all-link--pro" href="<?php echo site_url("product_view/".$pro['id']."/".$pro['slug'])?>">   
            <img class="img-fluid img-size" src="<?php echo base_url("assets/img/posts/".$pro['main_img'])?>">
            <p><?php echo $pro['title'] ?></p>
            <p><?php echo $pro['categoryname'] ?></p>
            <p>Rs. <?php echo $pro['price']; ?></p>
         </a>      
        </div> 
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: hello dear Alex, what ever code u have provided me are excellent and best in class but , slide problem is there. When it all appen then the previous products remian same.. I mean all fetched data remain then category append to that. It would be better if I can do it by removing the old listing products

Comment: You mean you want to remove the products you;ve already generated on page load with the foreach in the view? Just clear the HTML for the products div when you select a category.

Comment: Thats best..another asking is can i get the firstload value when i uncheck the all category ?

Comment: see js function changed

Comment: that's working but when uncheck the last checked result appended with first_load

Comment: I can't express how much I am now. Thank you so much...You just gave me more than 24hrs to solve my function. Thanks buddy

Comment: happy to hear it! i think you might want to look into a plugin called isotope (masonry-type plugin). its a smarter version of what you are trying to accomplish and it does some effects and such.

Comment: But the plugin is for the wordpress  only ?

Comment: i'm not sure how to integrate it with ajax as I usually load all the content all at once since i've never got that much. but if you have a lot, like in an ecommerce site, you could probably load say 10-20 items of every category initially. then when a user clicks a specific cat(s) then have those 20 items come in (by default) and have a load more type button. again, i've got no experience with this but i'm sure the functionality is there. anyways good luck!